# Cannot hit server side controller from Angular

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

When I try to call a server side controller using angularJS I get these two error messages.

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'problemId' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'Boolean ReadOnly(System.Guid)'

[11:55:27 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to send message to browser link server:
Error: SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()
```

**Server Side Controller** 
I've put a break point on this controller but it never gets hit.

```
public bool ReadOnly(Guid problemId)
        {
            var problem = new Problem(problemId);
            return problem.ProblemCompleted();
        }
```

**Angular Controller**
Ive stepped through the Angular and I have a valid GUID the whole way through.

```
$scope.problemCompleted = stepService.readOnly($scope.problemId);
```

**Angular Service**

```
//readOnly
this.readOnly = function (problemId) {
    $http.post(ROOT + '/step/ReadOnly/' + problemId)
   .then(function (result) {
       this.problemCompleted = result.data;
       return this.problemCompleted
   });
}
```

So I'm basically looking to get back the boolean value to my scope but I cant hit the controller.

Comment: How is the server side route defined?

Comment: You're dead right I just spotted it there Thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool ReadOnly(Guid problemId)
        {
            var problem = new Problem(problemId);
            return problem.ProblemCompleted();
        }
```

Rookie mistake changed problemId to id and it works .. sorry

```
public bool ReadOnly(Guid id)
        {
            var problem = new Problem(id);
            return problem.ProblemCompleted();
        }
```